# Microsoft Excel - slow to open

Tags: excel, ms-office

At my job I have to open up MS Excel many times a day. Starting Excel/opening an .xlsx file takes a few seconds, which from my understanding comes from loading multiple AddIns that we need for work.
This is annoying.

Is there a way to start Excel without Addins (to get a quick start) and to have an option to load in the AddIns if needed? (For context: often times we need to read an xlsx file without using any macros / addins)
For example something like writing a macro to load in the usual Addins.
(I know there is an option in Excel to tick the Addins you want to load but this is a bit tideous..)

Thanks for any tips/recommendations!
-Paul

Comment: Try some of these options  ...  https://bettersolutions.com/excel/workbooks/startup-switches.htm

Comment: Holding down the ctrl key usually works as the link says.

Comment: Thank you, the site was what I was looking for. 
Does holding control also work when opening a file? Because it only seems to work for me when starting the excel application but when I double click a .xlsx file while holing ctrl it opens as usual.

Comment: I can create a desktop shortcut of excel that opens in safe mode (or embedded mode)
but I need to somehow put a hotkey on the "open with" menu in order to select the safe mode version of excel when I need it..

Answer (score 1):

We used to have a bat file open Word and Excel, I think called from the Autoexec as the last statement. Once open we never quit Excel or Word - always kept a small file open...

We did this as there were a limited number of licenses and if you did not get one then you could go all day without Excel or Word...

Two of us had this and we did it for the secretary (who helped us a lot) then the rest of the department got wind so we did it for them as well. Never let on as there were over a 1000 possible users on site and we needed the advantage.